# Bind List of Classes into DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I need to bind a `List<MyClass> myList` to a `DataGridView`. And get in the results table with two columns ID and Name.

Code snippets:

```
private List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>(){...};

public void BindClass()
{
    dataGridView.DataSource = myList;
}

public MyClass
{
   public MyDataClass Data{ get; set; }
}

public MyDataClass
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You just asked the exact question. Delete this one. And edit the previous one if needed. Edit: I see you did delete the previous one. That is not the correct way as everyone that attempted to help you, answers's are now gone.

Comment: Sorry.. previous question was not correct..

Comment: Yes I got a downvote without reason and you deleted the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about binding to an anonymous type:

```
public void BindClass() 
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = myList.Select(myClass => new {myClass.Data.ID, myClass.Data.Name}).ToList();
}
```

Will you be updating the data in the datagridview ?

Comment: WOW, Very elegant solution! Thanks!

Comment: yes ill be updating. what should we do ? (for further reference to other users.)

Answer (score 2):

To do that without changing the model is **exceptionally** tricky (but possible), requiring `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`, and a custom `PropertyDescriptor`. To be honest: not worth it.

Just add pass-thru properties:

```
public MyClass
{
   public MyDataClass Data{get; set;}
   [DisplayName("ID")]
   public string DataID {
     get {return Data.ID;}
     set {Data.ID = value;}
   }
   [DisplayName("Name")]
   public string DataName {
     get {return Data.Name;}
     set {Data.Name = value;}
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution take place :)

Comment: Hmmm, I did never thought about doing this directly via the TypeDescriptor, it might have been a little easier than the BindingSource route I took  :)

Comment: @leppie - it is still pretty advanced stuff, though

Comment: Especially dealing with recursive data and a resultset of 1000's of properties. I had to limit my nesting to 6 levels and to 600 to prevent the DataGridView designer blowing up. Apparently, it does not like having more than ~650 columns  (funny enough, it is the fillfactor that is causing that limitation, 100 * 660 > 0xffff).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with LINQ as you can see in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502827/why-isnt-this-linq-query-on-dictionarytkey-tvalue-working-as-datasource)

Here's a simple implementation of something I needed to attach to datagridview.

```
     DataGridView1.DataSource =  _
(From i In ItemList Select i.ListID, i.FullName, i.PurchaseDesc, i.EditSequence).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this out of the box. You will have to write a custom binding source (most likely with specialized logic for your specific purpose) to allow 'drilling' deeper than just 1 level of properties.