# Why isn't this Linq query on Dictionary<TKey, TValue> working as DataSource

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, datagridview, datasource

I have the following in VB:

```
Dim sources = From source In importSources Select New With _
    {.Type = source.Key, .Source = source.Value.Name}

dgridSourceFiles.DataSource = sources
```

When I debug, `sources` shows an in-memory query and has 2 records within. Yet the datagrid view will not show the records.

*So why won't this work?* suggestions can be either VB or C#...

#### Update

When I use:

```
Dim sources = (From source In importSources Select New With _
    {.Type = source.Key, .Source = source.Value.Name}).ToList()
```

...the datasource is displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your LINQ query is lazily evaluated and implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface only (as far as I know), which means its results are not established until an enumerator calls `MoveNext` somewhere (as happens within a `foreach` loop, for example).

It seems the `DataSource` property does not enumerate its contents in this way. It's completely expecting an implementation of `IList` (or one of a few other interfaces—see below) so that it can access items by index. This is used internally by the control for sorting, filtering, etc. With this in mind, it's likely that all setting the `DataSource` property does is check the object's type to see whether it implements any of the supported interfaces. So I don't think the `DataSource` property is designed to deal with this type of object (a lazily evaluated query) at all.

Now, that `ToList` call populates a `List<T>` with the results of your query; this *does* implement `IList` and can therefore be used as the `DataSource`.

My understanding is that the reason `DataSource` is typed merely as `object` is that it expects *any* of the following interfaces:

- [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx)
- [`IListSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource.aspx) (in which case the `IListSource.GetList` method is used together with the `DataMember` property to provide data to the control)
- [`IBindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx) (which propagates changes in the list to the control for UI updates)
- [`IBindingListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview.aspx) (like [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx))

This is according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx).

Comment: I don't think so. The MSDN documentation on DataSource says that it must be Nothing or implement IEnumerable or IListSource. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.datasource.aspx

Comment: @jwiscarson: The link you posted is for `System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList`, not `DataGridView` (which is a Windows Forms control).

Comment: @Dan, you're right, and also right about the DataSource object for WinForms grids. The OP needs to update this post clarifying WebForms vs. WinForms. I misunderstood "datagrid view" as a generic viewing of a datagrid.

Comment: @jwiscarson: It could certainly be clearer, but the question does include the tag `datagridview`; so I *think* we're talking WinForms here.

Comment: Agreed, and +1. I never submitted an answer to this question because the question was so confusing, and had no idea what minute detail could be missing from the post that would've led to this problem, so your answer is especially insightful.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call DataBind after setting the source. Try:

```
dgridSourceFiles.DataSource = sources
dgridSourceFiles.DataBind()
```

Comment: I do not have a `DataBind()` method on DataGridView. I had thought of that when I saw another solution.

Comment: @dboarman: Duly noted. I've been living mostly in the Web world, so I was thinking of a GridView control. :-)